# One More Holiday Rebus!

Tags: rebus, seasonal

I've made three of these so far... but here's another one! The toughest one so far.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rebus is

> **I will honor Christmas in my heart and try to keep it all the year.**
>
>  A line by Ebenezer Scrooge to the ghost of Christmas Yet to Come in Charles Dickens' "A Christmas Carol"

Explanation:

> "eye" (by sound) -> **I**
>  some actor/character named **WILL**
>  **H** + [g]**ON**[e] + **O** + **R**
>  image of **CHRIST**-
>  "plus" in Spanish = más -> -**MAS**
>  image of [g]**IN**
>  **MY**
>  image of a **HEART**
>  **AND TRY TO**
>  image of **KE**[y] + **EP**
>  **IT ALL THE**
>  image of a calendar **YEAR**